# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DNNClassifier'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Trying to repoduce the results from the Tensorflow tutorial based on the Iris Data set
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator

However I am unable to run it as there is the Attribute Error
I am running this on the official docker tensorflow jupyter image

[image: error output]

Comment: upgrade your tensorflow version to 1.3.0

Comment: @IshantMrinal awesome was able bash into the docker container and pip install tensorflow to upgrade.

any recommendation on the best docker image to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close the question officially: only the (right now) newest tensorflow release 1.3.0 has the DNNClassifier included (see release notes: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/RELEASE.md), so you need to upgrade your tensorflow version to use it:)